# A strange behavior of TCP send function

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a test for TCP connection about multithreading, and there is a strange phenomenon that I cannot solve.

The program is quite simple.  We have a server to accept and three clients to connect.  In the end, the server will call `send()` to return state to client and do loops like it.  But unfortunately, when the server accepts about 30000 connections, it stops to return to the client, and the client will time out and exit.

I have tried to increase the system port range, reduce time-wait seconds, and slow down the TCP connection speed, but it did not work and closed the socket correctly.

Is there any other reason?
client code :

```
    while ( true )
    /*connect server */
{
    initSocketLocal(&client_addr,0);//
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if( client_socket < 0)
    {
        printf("Create Socket Failed!\n");
        return -1;    
    }
    if( bind(client_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,sizeof(client_addr)))
    {
        printf("Client Bind Port Failed!\n");
        close(client_socket);
        return -1;
    }
    initSocket(&server_addr,DATANODE_PORT_READ,ip);

    if((connect(client_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_addr_length)) < 0)
    {
        perror ("can not connect to server:");  //find error
        printf("client count is %d...\n", clientCount);
        return -1;

    }
    usleep ( 100000 ) ;
    clientCount++;
    printf("client count is %d...\n", clientCount);

    int length = recv ( client_socket ,res ,sizeof ( res ), 0);
    if (length > 0)
    {
        printf ("recv buf is %s \n", res );
    }
    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

and  sever code as fllows :

```
while(  true )
    /*wait for connect*/
{
    socklen_t length  =   sizeof (struct  sockaddr );

    printf("listening ..... \n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_read);//lock clifd

    if ((clifd  =  accept(sockRead,( struct  sockaddr * ) & cliaddr, & length)) < 0 )
    {
        perror ("can not accept socket:");
        break;
    }

    printf("Read Accept fd %d\n",clifd);

    pthread_create (&t,NULL,handler,&clifd);

}


void* handler(void*arg)

{
    int fd = *((int *)arg);

    sockCount ++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_read);
    char  ret [ 10 ];

    printf("accept sock count is :  %d !\n",sockCount);
    usleep ( 100000 ) ;

    strcpy ( ret ,"ok" );
    send ( fd, ret, strlen (ret ), 0);//blocked when sockCount reach to 32571..
    printf ("send ok ..\n");
    close (fd);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
~
```

Comment: this program is quite simple ,and close connection in time,I have added  range of ports ,but it did not do anything ..

Comment: Define "stops to return to the client". Doesn't mean anything to me. Do you mean "stops sending"? And you will have to post some code, no matter how simple you think it may be.

Comment: @user2864740 What exactly does `SO_REUSEADDR` have to do with it?

Comment: @EJP yes,when server have reach 32571 connections in total,it stop to send return messages to the client ..I'll post my code .thanks.

Comment: If you fixed your error handling so that there actually was some, you might have some hope of discovering what is going on. If any of those socket functions return -1, you should call `perror()` or print a string including the appropriate `strerror` value. At the moment it's just a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're reaching the maximum number of connections. There as a limit of 64K connections from a client to a server on a given port. It is also possible to limit the number of connections in the firewall. Also, you might try putting a 5 millisecond (or so) pause in between each connection.

Comment: it seems that the number of ports and connections are not limit factors,because I modify my program accept every 0.01s,and client start connect every 0.01s,that menas 300 connections per seconds in all .

Comment: This suggestion doesn't account for the problem. It appears to be a sending problem, not a connection problem, and in any case 30000 is a lot less than 3 x 65535.

Answer (score 0):

Also print the fd value in addition to sockCount in handler(), you are approaching 32k. What does 'ulimit -n' show for the number of file descriptors?

You have a race condition in handler(), it unlocks the mutex early allowing fd to be modified by the other thread while it's still in use.